# generates simple_form with Bootstrap4 don't work's

Tags: hadoop-yarn, twitter-bootstrap-4, simple-form-for, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm generating simple_form with bootstrap4 on Rails 5.1, so I search in the web and try these ways:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap4
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap4 --force
```

And no one of that generates the file configured like: `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb`

I watch with version is installed and is the version of `simple_form 1.4.1`. I try to put the new version 3.2.1 but I have errors when run the `bundle update` command.
And I have these errors:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:

rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0)

rspec-rails (~> 3.5) was resolved to 3.6.0, which depends on
  actionpack (>= 3.0)

simple_form (~> 3.2.1) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
  actionpack (< 5.1, > 4)
```

I'm trying to do an application with the new version rails 5.1. Anyone could help me I will appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I just see the version of rails 5.1 isn't compatible with this gem actually!
If someone want to see here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/commit/8d15b7ebc8096348b611e9f2905a2576a5bce508